# Year over Year growth column calculation in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data of the following format with the desired 'QoQ_growth' column:

```
   FIPS             year     qtr          Category     sales    QoQ_growth
0   1001            2019      1           Furniture    1000     NaN
1   1001            2019      2           Furniture    1100     0.1
2   1001            2019      3           Furniture    1200     0.0909
3   1001            2019      4           Furniture    1300     0.0833
4   1001            2020      1           Furniture    1400     0.0769
5   1001            2020      2           Furniture    1500     0.0714
```

I need to arrive to this new column df['QoQ_growth'], which would be growth of the Sales column from the previous quarter within a certain FIPS and Category. I've got a ton of FIPS codes, 40 years of data and five categories. So I was thinking of doing:

```
df.groupby(['FIPS', 'year', 'qtr', 'Category'])['Sales'].pct_change()
```

But this won't work. Neither practically (outputs all NaNs for unknown reason) nor theoretically. Since if I do this groupby, it will only calculate QoQ growth within a certain year. It will not calculate growth from Q4 1975 to Q1 1976 for example since we group by year. Can't understand how should I get to the desired output?

My ultimate desired output would answer questions like for example - "By how much sales grew by quarter in Furniture category in FIPS #2050 from 1975 to 2020?"

Comment: Maybe I’m misunderstanding, but wouldn’t simply doing `df.groupby('Category')['Sales'].pct_change()` work?

Comment: Do you have missing quarter in your data? if yes how you want to handle it?

Comment: @BertilJohannesIpsen  It then ignores the FIPS. So following your advice df.groupby(['FIPS', 'category'])['Sales'].pct_change() should potentially output a pd series with growth values. Each FIPS should then start with a NaN, which it does. But still need to check the values. Thanks though. Some food for thought.

Comment: @Ben.T I don't think I do. but if I do, then I think it's fine to get me the growth to the next available quarter. So assuming that I have 1980 Q4 missing, which means I would have the entire row missing, I'd like growth from 1980 Q3 to 1981 Q1. If your question was that I have missing values - I don't. It might be the case that entire row is missing.

Comment: ok so you are right, just groupby on FIPS and category will give you the result you want. in case your data is not ordered (of just to be sure) you can consider to do sort_values before the groupby `df.sort_values(['year','qtr']).groupby(....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**

This should work reliable in case FIPS change happens.

```
df.groupby(['FIPS', 'year', 'qtr', 'Category']).sum().groupby(['FIPS', 'Category']).pct_change()
```

---

You can't apply series-wide function to a groupby object. (You can, but it just affects the group; not to result of groupby operation.) First convert it to series via .sum(), then apply your function. It should work.

```
df.groupby(['FIPS', 'year', 'qtr', 'Category'])['sales'].sum().pct_change()
```

or

```
df.groupby(['FIPS', 'year', 'qtr', 'Category'])['sales'].apply(lambda x: x).pct_change()
```

Output:

```
df.groupby(['FIPS', 'year', 'qtr', 'Category'])['sales'].sum().pct_change()
FIPS  year  qtr  Category 
1001  2019  1    Furniture         NaN
            2    Furniture    0.100000
            3    Furniture    0.090909
            4    Furniture    0.083333
      2020  1    Furniture    0.076923
            2    Furniture    0.071429
Name: sales, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you. seems to work. I was thinking why it didn't work, but it never output an error so I though I did something inherently wrong.

Comment: The function you provide for groupby looks for groupby items, in your case ['FIPS', 'year', 'qtr', 'Category']. So, summing would sum these groups; not the series you see. If you want to do operations on the series you want to see, then first get that series you want to see, then apply your desired function to it. I'm glad I was able to help.

Comment: @RuslanAskerov be aware that the `pct_change` is not done per group with this method. what make it work is that df.groupby(['FIPS', 'year', 'qtr', 'Category'])['sales'].sum() will order you data such that pct_change after will give you almost the expected result. You will have value in the rows where a new FIPS category ha[ens while you should not have a value here

Comment: @Ben.T is right. This would work though.

df.groupby(['FIPS', 'year', 'qtr', 'Category']).sum().groupby(['FIPS']).pct_change()

Comment: @Ben.T you're exactly right - df.groupby(['FIPS', 'year', 'qtr', 'Category'])['sales'].sum() this works per FIPS, but then for the next FIPS it breaks down.

Comment: @GokturkSahin seem to work, mate. Thx. I'll check it out closely today.

Comment: @RuslanAskerov df.groupby(['FIPS', 'year', 'qtr', 'Category']).sum().groupby(['FIPS', 'Category']).pct_change()

don't forget, i added category as well later :)

Comment: @GokturkSahin I just came back here to write that also need to add category and found your comment! :)) nice. yeah, while checking, I figured that myself.

Comment: @GokturkSahin could you please explain how the double groupby works? I understand the groupby concept fairly well. so I see what's happening before the second groupby. But then I don't understand the mechanism.

Comment: @RuslanAskerov the problem is .pct_change() needs a series to do its job. When you groupby with fips, year, qtr, category, we get a nice table with grouped variables; then we apply .sum(). why? because this would give me one series, this one just starts from first data and goes on. and remember, pct_change() needs series.

however after this, year-category-fips does not make any difference when applying pct_change since we got a whole series for the dataframe. so i created many series with unique fips and category, so we have (fips*category) series now; for each i can apply pct_change